# wpf validation rules problem with textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, validationrules

I created a class IntegersValidationRule which inherits from ValidationRule. Now I don't know what code should I write in XAML. That's what I have:

```
<TextBox Name="defaultTxt"
     Height="23" Width="200">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <what:IntegersValidationRule/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I know that either I'm so stupid that I can't understand in many tutorials what Path in Binding property means, why should we use Binding here when there's no binding required and what should I use instead of 'what' word inside Binding.ValidationRule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`what` is an `xmlns` ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx)) which needs to point to the namespace in which your validation rule class is declared, e.g.

```
xmlns:what="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyValidationRules"
```

If you add no [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) (*- how about reading this if you do not understand it? -*) the binding will bind to the current [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx), whatever that may be in your case.

Answer (score 1):

- Question 1: validators work on bindings. That is why you specify the rule on a binding. As soon as then value will be updated to the source (object that the control binds to) the rule is checked.
- Question 2: See H.B. 's answer